# How to reshape the dimension of data cube in DM with script

Tags: dm-script

I have an image with dimensions 1024*1024 stored in a HDF5 file, which is treated as a data cube of slice thickness 1, (so that stored dimension is 1024*1024*1) . I used the Niermann HDF5 plug-in (https://github.com/niermann/gms_plugin_hdf5) to import the data. After importing, the data cube became 1*1024*1024, and displayed as 1 pixel wide, 1024 pixels hight and 1024 slices images.

Before considering re-implement the plug-in, I'd like to ask, is there any way to "reshape" the data (like in "Numpy.reshape"), so that the dimensions can be properly treated?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume that the command Slice2() may help, but I could not still follow the instructions and examples in "DM scripting handbook"

Comment: Thanks for the very useful link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't like icol, irow and these expressions, another elegant solution is to just use the streaming object.

```
image ReShape3D( image input, number sx, number sy, number sz )
{
    // Perform testing
    number nPix=1
    for ( number d=0; d<input.ImageGetNumDimensions(); d++ )
        nPix *= input.ImageGetDimensionsize(d)

    if ( sx*sy*sz < nPix ) Throw( "Input image larger than provided shape." )
    if ( sx*sy*sz > nPix ) Throw( "Input image smaller than provided shape." )

    image reShaped := input.Imageclone()
    reShaped.ImageResize(3,sx,sy,sz)
    object dStream = NewStreamFromBuffer(0)
    ImageWriteImageDataToStream(input,dStream,0)
    dStream.StreamSetPos(0,0)
    ImageReadImageDataFromStream(reShaped,dStream,0)
    return reshaped
}

Image before := RealImage("Before",4,10,20,30)
before = random()
Image after := ReShape3D( before,20,10,30 )
before.ShowImage()
after.ShowImage()
```

Comment: Streaming seems a nice way in dealing with i/o :-)

Answer (score 1):

If your input/output array sizes do not match in dimension (such that `slice` would not work), then you can also 'stream' the data into and out of 1D using the following:

```
number sx = 4   
number sy = 5   
number sz = 2   

image oneLine := RealImage( "1D",4, sx*sy*sz )
oneLine = icol
oneLine.ShowImage()

image reShape1Dto3D := RealImage( "1D->3D", 4, sx, sy, sz )
reShape1Dto3D = oneLine[icol + iwidth*irow + iwidth*iheight*iplane, 0 ]
reShape1Dto3D.ShowImage()

image reShape3Dto1D := RealImage( "3D->1D", 4, sx*sy*sz )
reShape3Dto1D[icol + iwidth*irow + iwidth*iheight*iplane, 0 ] = reShape1Dto3D
reShape3Dto1D.ShowImage()
```

The trick here is, that you can address a single value in an image expression using square-brackets. In a 3D image by [X,Y,Z], in a 2D image by [X,Y], and in a 1D images as [X,0]. <sup>[*]</sup>

The internal variables `icol`, `irow`, `iplane` are replaced by X,Y,Z coordinate of the evaluated expression, whereas  `iwidth`, `iheight` and `idepth` are replaced by the dimension sizes of the evaluated expression.

What is the *evaluated expression*'s size? It becomes defined by the only image of "known size" in the line - either left or right side, so that

```
reShape1Dto3D = oneLine[ icol + iwidth*irow + iwidth*iheight*iplane, 0 ]
```

becomes a loop over X/Y/Z of all pixels of *reShape1Dto3D* an the lefthand side of the expression. For each triplet (X/Y/Z) the value is taken from the computed position of *oneLine*.

Exactly the same is used in

```
reShape3Dto1D[ icol + iwidth*irow + iwidth*iheight*iplane, 0 ] = reShape1Dto3D
```

but here the loop is again over the size of *reShape1Dto3D*, because that is the image of "known size" in the line, even if it is on the righthand side.

<sup>* Higher dimensionality is not supported in this way, as [T,L,B,R] is already used for sub-areas.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

After few more trial with the examples in "DM scripting handbook", a method is figured out:

```
image out = in.slice2(0,0,0, 1,1024,1, 2,1024,1)
```

that is, the output 2d image in the x-y take the projection of y-z plane of the input image using Slice2() command.

Comment: This will work, but it copies the data (and nothing else). You might want to consider using `image out := in.slice2(0,0,0, 1,1024,1, 2,1024,1)` if you just want to address that area, or `image out := in.slice2(0,0,0, 1,1024,1, 2,1024,1).ImageClone()` to create a clone (including tags, calibration etc.)